# How do I simulate clicking a child Tab and call the onClick handler that is defined in the Parent container using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-bootstrap

My development code works but it's the test that doesn't.
Tabs and Tab are components from the react-bootstrap library.

An abbreviated version of my dev code:

```
<Tabs data-testid='testTabs' onSelect={handleSelect}>
                        <Tab data-testid='testBtn' eventKey='hello'></Tab>
                        <Tab data-testid='testBtn2' eventKey='goodbye'></Tab>
                    </Tabs>
```

An abbreviated version of my test code:

```
let wrapper = mount(<MyComponent/>);
await wrapper.find('[data-testid="testBtn"]').hostNodes().simulate('select');
```

Unfortunately the onSelect handler never gets called.
I can call get it to be called if I add the onSelect handle function to the Tab (example below) but I'd rather not do this for every tab.

```
<Tab data-testid='testBtn' eventKey='hello' onSelect={() => { handleSelect('hello'); }}></Tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `click event` on `Tab`

```
await wrapper.find('[data-testid="testBtn"]').simulate('click');
await wrapper.find('[data-testid="testBtn2"]').simulate('click');
```

Comment: yes, I've tried this as well but same outcome

Comment: No.  The test fails further down but there is no error from the simulate.